# Can an SPA issue parallel async queries against a single GraphQL server?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

GraphQL usually serves at a single endpoint.  Can I have, for example, an SPA page with a half dozen live status displays each making an independent promise-wrapped request to that same endpoint?  The query payloads take time to assemble and will not complete in the same order as requests were received.  Further, some status payloads may take seconds or longer to complete.  I don't want to batch the requests, I want the data for each display delivered as soon as its data is available.

Comment: Sounds as if you need subscriptions (which are not yet ready in graphql-java). Other than that, I don't get what makes this scenario special? Why would concurrent requests be a problem?

Comment: They are not.  Total noob question that was the result of a single endpoint, not being aware that resolvers could return promises, and the serial nature of graphiql (it ignores responses from all but the most recent query).   To test I added a resolver that returns a promise wrapping a setTimeout resolving a response after a random timeout.  Then I just manually submit a quick series of queries.  They overlap and resolve properly just as desired.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I've also played with a subscriptions - exciting stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, you will lose one of the benefits of GraphQL but other than the small amount of latency that the GraphQL server adds, you won't experience downsides until you run into needing to horizontally scale the GraphQL server.